# Find/Remove (keep only Numbers)

Tags: regex, notepad++

Have a text file with

```
123.234.531.123.5363
Text : some words here... 
Words : awesome//great+++
Rate : 2,231

131.53234.2414.5345.634
Text : some words here... 
Words : painfull//sad
Rate : 182,21
```

Now I need **only** the long numbers:

```
123.234.531.123.5363
131.53234.2414.5345.634
```

What I should use as find/replace?

**edit:** My problem solved with `^\D.*$`

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is the regex for the search, this might work:

```
\d+\.[.\d]+
```

Comment: That removes all the Numbers and not keep them :/

Answer (score 0):

If you use OS Windows, you can use regular expression in Notepad++
http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html

[image]