# Notepad ++ - keep numbers only

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file containing numbers and characters (in arabic)

like this:

943894رنيش964737

ترشقة1045051

ضمنزلبالق10653

to this:

943894964737

1045051

10653

I want to remove everything apart from the numbers

I looked at a possible solution here:

[Find/Remove (keep only Numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345388/find-remove-keep-only-numbers)

But its not working for me, plus its not very clear to me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use regex replace with this regex: `[^\d]` and replace with empty string

```
press ctrl+f
goto replace tab
check regular expressions
put '[^\d]' in search
press 'replace all'
```

use this regex if you want to keep line breaks: `[^\d\r\n]`

Comment: he want to remove the arabic characters not numbers.

Comment: @user1671639: you obviously don't know what the circumflex does.

Comment: hmm thats putting the numbers all on the same line, basically its got numbers and arabic characters on seperate lines, for some reason when i posted the question, it placed it all on one line :/

Comment: @BenYermak well, u said `I want to remove everything apart from the numbers` , thats exactly what it does, you didnt say anything about putting new lines in there. maybe give a `before` => `after` example. so its clear what you want

Comment: @BenYermak look at the edit of my post, that should work for you, and please mark as answer if it's what u were looking for

Comment: but what is the expression if I have hexadecimal characters ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to @x4rf41 idea

If You are working with some Excel-like data, where You got columns, copying this data to Notepad++ makes breaks between columns with tab ("\t"). So if You want to keep this breaks, or just leave the column breaks when you put them back into Excel, you have to use:

```
[^\d\r\n\t]
```

so you will leave tabs and data will remain in the correct structure when You will copy it to Excel back. Of course, I don't know if you really need it, but I did and I leave a note for others. :)