# how can i remove specific lines in notepd++

Tags: notepad++

I have a big csv file which contains numbers in every line .

There are random lines with some words which i want removed .

Its something like this :

```
128917918279817
109829809180809809809
12908121214
12982981
Hey i want to remove these
2139080921
23987897239087
3289897812
12398209180980
Another line to be removed
123809182091
12093801928
324098230980890
```

Is there anyway I can remove just lines which contains words and lines with numbers remain there .

My issue is to remove those character lines , I have tried searching everywhere but unable to find any proper answer .

Comment: Somehow in my example above lines are not shown due to formatting .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad ++ - keep numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274611/notepad-keep-numbers-only)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove certain lines, I would suggest to use Find / Replace feature and use "Regular Expression" option:

In the **Find what** text box use the text "**\r\n[a-z]+.***"
In **Replace with** text box, use empty string (i.e. nothing should be there in the text box)
It would replace all lines with only characters with empty string.

Hope this helps.

[image: The image for Find and Replace in Notepad++]

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\D+\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  \D+       # 1 or more NON digits
  \R        # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
128917918279817
109829809180809809809
12908121214
12982981
2139080921
23987897239087
3289897812
12398209180980
123809182091
12093801928
324098230980890
```

If you want to remove lines that may contain some digits but not ONLY digits, use

- Find: `^.*[^\d\r\n]+.*\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`